# Default animation direction of Editing Accessory

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, accessoryview

I've noticed that during a table view's transition to editing mode, the editing accessory can slide in from the left or from the right (it also fades in at the same time, so you have to watch carefully).  The logic seems to be that if there is an accessory in view mode, then the editing accessory slides in from the left.  Otherwise, it slides in from the right.  I tested this setting up some standard accessories in IB.

I have a custom cell that assigns its own editing accessory.  When I switch to editing mode, the editing accessory slides in from the left, as though there is not an accessory already in place in view mode.

How can I resolve this, and force the transition to occur from the right?  A link to some documentation on these guidelines would also be appreciated.